# Send data from three forms to the controller

Tags: php, laravel, controller

I created three different forms they need to be separated because they are collapsed in different buttons. It happens that I would like my controller to receive data from the three forms when I click on a submit button on the third form. Is it possible to receive input data from all forms with a single submit in Laravel?

Each form is inside a button identified by a data-target. Example:

```html
<div class="container" id="myGroup">   
 
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#entidade"  role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="entidade">
          Entidades
    </button>  

    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#dirigente1"  role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="dirigente1">
            Dirigente 1
    </button>        

    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#dirigente2"  role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="dirigente2">
            Dirigente 2
    </button>   
    
    <form  class="collapse" id="entidade" data-parent="#myGroup" method="post" action="/entidades/store">
    .
    .
    </form>

    <form  class="collapse" id='dirigente1' data-parent="#myGroup" method="post" action="/entidades/store">           
    .
    .
    </form>

    <form  class="collapse" id='dirigente2' data-parent="#myGroup" method="post" action="/entidades/store">           
    .
    .
    </form>
</div>
```

Controller:

```php
public function store(Request $request){
    
}
```

Comment: Put other 2 form elements inside 3rd form and have a single form on the webpage.

Comment: I did not understand how this is possible .... could you exemplify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks guys, I solved the problem leaving everything in a single form.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to put all your forms into one, and that means have only one form tag that will send a POST request to your controller.

I would suggest implementing the logic in your controller that would handle empty fields and save only those fields that are not empty (i.e. if you leave first two forms blank and submit only the third one)

You can still keep all 3 submit buttons, but make sure to merge all forms into one, so you have only one form tag in a page like this:

```html
<form method='POST' action='...'>
  ...form 1 inputs...
  ...submit button 1

  ...form 2 inputs...
  ...submit button 2

  ...form 3 inputs...
  ...submit button 3
</form>
```

Comment: How do I do if I have 3 different toogles in each form?

Comment: What do you mean by toogles? You can have any type of input fields as this will all be ONE form

Comment: lyyka, 
I have 3 collapsed buttons and each one has an associated form. When I click on one of them it opens a different form. So, if I create an external form the collapsed button will stop working.